# Implementing an interface in Java - Why does javap output two methods with the same signature but different return type?

Tags: java, jls, javap

Given this Java code:

```java
interface I {
  Object getId();
}

class A implements I {
  public Long getId() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```
javac I.java A.java
```

It compiles successfully. When disassembled the class files produces the following output:

```
javap I.class
javap A.class
```

```
Compiled from "I.java"
interface I {
  public abstract java.lang.Object getId();
}

Compiled from "A.java"
class A implements I {
  A();
  public java.lang.Long getId();     <--- (1)
  public java.lang.Object getId();   <--- (2)
}
```

Question is **why two methods with the same signature (1) & (2) are present in the disassembled output** ?
Having two methods with the same signature - isn't it not something JLS disallows ?

Comment: What output do you get when `I` is a concrete base class?

Comment: ``Long getId()`` does not override ``Object getId()`` To override, it would require the same return type. The Long getId() hides the original method.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The output  of "javap A.class" is practically the same as posted in the question when `I` is a concrete base class (and `A extends I`); i.e. two methods with different return types.

Comment: @NomadMaker: I see ... But the hidden method is still preserved in the class file ... why is that needed ?